# Parent child interprocess comunication - is keeeping pipes open OK?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix

I have to implement a program in which a process sends data it has received from parent process to its child process, waits until the child sends him  processed data back, and then return processed data to child process (so e.g. in case of 4 processes the data flow would look like this `P1->P2->P3->P4->P3->P2->P1`). For means of interprocess communication I need to use pipes. Here's an approach I planned to take:

`./child`

```
// Assert argv contains 2 pipe descriptors - for reading
// from parent and for writing to parent, both of type char[]

// I'm not handling system errors currently

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int read_dsc, write_dsc;
    read_dsc = atoi(argv[1]);
    write_dsc = atoi(argv[2]);
    char data[DATA_SIZE];
    read (read_dsc, data, DATA_SIZE - 1);
    close (read_dsc);
    // Process data...
    (...)
    // Pass processed data further
    int pipeRead[2]; // Child process will read from this pipe
    int pipeWrite[2]; // Child process will write into this pipe
    pipe(pipeRead);
    pipe(pipeWrite);
    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            close (pipeRead[1]);
            close (pipeWrite[0]);
            char pipeReadDsc[DSC_SIZE];
            char pipeWriteDsc[DSC_SIZE];
            printf (pipeReadDsc, "%d", pipeRead[0]);
            printf (pipeWriteDsc, "%d", pipeWrite[1]);
            execl ("./child", "child", pipeReadDsc, pipeWriteDsc, (char *) 0);
        default:
            close(pipeRead[0]);
            close(pipeWrite[1]);
            wait(0);
            read (pipeWrite[0], data, DATA_SIZE - 1);
            close (pipeWrite[0]);
            // Pass data to parent process
            write (write_dsc, data, DATA_SIZE - 1);
            close (write_dsc);
    }
}
```

High level description of my solution is as follows: make 2 pipes, one for writing to child process, one for reading from child process. Wait until child process finishes and then read from read pipe and pass data to parent.

The problem is I don't know whether this approach is correct. I've read somewhere that not closing unused pipes is an error as it clutters OS file descriptors and there shouldn't be many opened pipes at once. Here however we're keping unclosed pipe for reading from a child and potentially if there are `n` processes, there are `n` opened pipes when process number `n` processes it's data (all parent processes are waiting for data to come back). However I can't see any other way to solve this problem...

So - is my solution correct? If it isn't, how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct. But there is problems in your code:

- case 0 is the child, you will benefit in redirecting pipe ends onto standard input and output (use `dup` or `dup2`); passing descriptor ids to the child is weird.
- default is the parent, so you need to `write` before `read`ing.

"not closing unused pipes is an error" : it is not an error but may cause problems (detecting the end of a communication would be difficult or impossible), but it seems that you correctly close all non useful pipe ends in your code, so ok. In general the number of open pipes is not really an issue, as open files...